# Allow different parameters without overloading method?

Tags: java, overloading

SOLVED: Thank you everyone for the help, I ended up overriding the method in Person like a couple of you said. My problem was that Character didn't even have doSomething, so what I ended up doing was simply adding doSomething to character and returning nothing. This is because I only had to worry about the a(a person).doSomething(b)(a character) case.

So, I have a method that takes two parameters, Character a and Character b.

```
 public static void giveMessage(Character a, Character b)
```

I want this method to also work if the parameters are Person a (which is a subclass of character), Character b

```
 public static void giveMessage(Person a, Character b)
```

I know I can do this by overloading the method, but it's followed by around 15 lines of code. So if I were to overload it 3 times it would become lengthy. I don't really have a problem with doing this, I'm just wondering if there is an easier way.

More info:

```
giveMessage(Character a, Character b){
    if(a instanceof Person){
       a.doSomething(b)
```

doSomething is only found in Person, so it gives me an error that it can't find it in Character.

Comment: You can define the several overloads and call a private method which holds the code they have in common, or you can work with generics.

Comment: Have you tried this? It should work as is I think

Comment: If `Person` is a subclass of `Character`, then it's not a different parameter. A Person **is** also a Character.

Comment: Although not preferable, you **could** use `instanceof` within the method to check the type. However, it is better if you call something like `a.giveMessage(b)` within the method and define `giveMessage` in the `Character` class. Then your `Person` class can override this method if it wants to behave differently.

Comment: I will try the first suggestion right now, and concerning the different parameter thing, I realized it's probably a method issue which I call alter on in the code. I talked more about this as a comment to the first answer, I'll also edit it into the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void giveMessage(Character a, Character b)
```

should work for Persons because its an implicit cast

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast (I know its c++ but this will work for java too)

it will automatically cast a person to a character

Comment: Hmmm yeah that's what I thought. Maybe the error is because I use a method solely located in the Person class. Inside giveMessage, if Character a is an instance of Person, I use a method doSomething(Character other), which is located only in Person. It ends up being something like a.doSomething(b). The error I get is that the method can't be found in the Character class.

Comment: you cant do it that way then. But maybe use a method of the same name in character and person. Then just override it

Comment: just add an empty function doSomething in character which does nothing

Comment: I think I can solve this if I change the location of doSomething, but I'm not really sure. If I solve it I'll update this.